Which has the faster heating time - PTC thermistors or an etched foil heater?
In evaluating which technology has the faster heating time, given an equal size/thermal mass and an equal voltage, which would be more likely to reach a temperature of 80C faster - a PTC heating elements or an etched foil heater?
This website says

The time constant of a thermistor, also referred to as time response or tau (τ), is conventionally defined as the amount of time for the signal measured by the thermistor to increase to 63.2% of its final value.
...
Standard RBR thermistors have a tau of less than 1s.

If this is the case, why would etched foil heaters be used instead of PTC heating elements, given that they do not have the same in built protection against over heating? Is it because etched foil heaters have a faster heating time?

How much power is each device dissipating? That matters, the technology doesn't. A thermistor would be an odd choice to use as a heater, though.

Whichever has the smallest thermal mass, thermal impedance and most power. Have you tried to calculate these parameters for your materials in question?

To correct these misconceptions about PTC heaters that you've put in your comment to another answer

I found this text on a supplier’s website “ PTC (Positive Temperature Coefficient) Heating Elements offer numerous advantages over traditional heating solutions. Their self-regulating nature ensures safety by preventing overheating, making them ideal for various applications. PTC elements are highly efficient, converting more energy into heat compared to conventional heaters. With rapid heating capabilities and long lifespan, they provide consistent warmth while saving energy costs.”

Their self-regulating nature - Yes. They are safer in domestic heaters than plain resistive heaters. If you throw a towel over the heater, the reduced airflow increases the element temperature until the PTC action reduces the power output to maintain their temperature at a safe level.
converting more energy into heat than conventional heaters ...  saving energy costs - No, this is a lie. All resistive electric heaters are 100% efficient.
I feel this is a dangerous lie, as it is used in advertising. People who cannot afford the heating they have could buy these products hoping for a saving, costing them even more money for no benefit. I have written to advertising standards authorities to see whether they can control these sorts of advertising claims, with no good responses.

PTC thermistor is a temperature sensing device, not a heater. A "fast" temperature sensor allows for faster adjustment of the heating power to maintain a more stable temperature but does not change how fast a device will reach a temperature.
For a PTC heating element the resistance will increase faster at increasing temperatures than a standard resistive element.
If both heaters deliver the same power at a lower temperatures then at higher temperatures by design the PTC heater will deliver less power than the resistive one.
Generally for faster heating you simply need a heater with a higher power rating(watts).

thank you. I maybe used the wrong word to describe the device. I found this text on a supplier’s website “ PTC (Positive Temperature Coefficient) Heating Elements offer numerous advantages over traditional heating solutions. Their self-regulating nature ensures safety by preventing overheating, making them ideal for various applications. PTC elements are highly efficient, converting more energy into heat compared to conventional heaters. With rapid heating capabilities and long lifespan, they provide consistent warmth while saving energy costs.” So I guess meant PTC heat elements - sorr

I think this is "optimistic marketing speak":  "converting more energy into heat over traditional heating solutions".

@EddieP Please edit your question to correct it.

@EddieP I have edited the answer to include PTC heaters.  :) hope that helps.

@EddieP Please edit your question to include the quote above about converting more energy into heat. Normally I would add comments to the original question, but this would change the meaning of the question a little, so feel you should do it rather than me.

@Kezat thank you kindly.

Etched foil heaters will output 100W of heat consistently as long as they are supplied with 100W of power.
PTC heaters may initially output close to 100W but reduce output over time as their resistance increases, making them self-regulating.
So unless the Etched foil reaches a critical temperature and disintegrates or you regulate it externally, the Etched foil should take the lead.
Ultimately the real question is heat transfer. It's one thing to heat the heater. But at equal power, the more efficient heater is the one with better heat transfer.

To heat a test mass fast, the best way is to dissipate heat in the mass itself if possible. Examples include induction heating of bearings, and cookware for that matter.
If the heat has to come from a separate heater, then improve the thermal conductivity between heater and heated, and reduce the mass of the heater.
All resistive electrical heaters heat at 100% power in to heat out efficiency. The only difference is their physical form, and how easy it is to get a robust thermal contact to them.
We would ideally allow the heating element to get much hotter than the final aiming temperature of the payload. This allows us to drive heat through the electrical insulation faster. A low mass heater will ensure little or no overshoot when the payload finally gets up to temperature. If a PTC heater has a 'shut-down' temperature close to the target temperature, then this excess heater temperature won't occur, and the heat delivery will slow prematurely.

A PTC heater is a kind of crude control system with a fixed temperature setpoint setting and relatively low proportional gain. It may also add significant mass in the form of itself, which also has to be heated. The 'sensor' is part of the heater so the heater itself will maintain a more-or-less fixed temperature with variations in losses and supply voltage but that may not reflect the temperature of the object being heated accurately.
A thin-film heater has little mass (mostly the substrate) so the total mass to be heated may be dominated by whatever it is that you are heating. As part of a closed-loop control system you can make the setpoint whatever you want and the heater will try to respond, limited by the control authority it has. You can put the sensor in a more advantageous position (such as attached to, or inside,
the object being heated), rather than inside the heater which is almost always
a better choice. Depending on the losses and the construction you may be able to get it to withstand a 100% power-on control failure (though whatever is being controlled may be damaged).
In both cases the time to heat will depend on the power, total mass and heat losses due to conduction, convection and radiation. To the extent those vary, there will be differences in performance. The low-gain PTC heater system will slow down before the crude 'setpoint' is reached so it may take longer to stabilize to a more-or-less steady temperature (mathematically, it actually never quite gets to the final temperature, but it gets 'close enough' depending on your definition of close enough and practical factors).  For an application such as heat tracing the PTC system may require a higher setpoint than would otherwise be required to keep the pipe from freezing on the coldest days, however the simplicity may make up for the additional energy costs.
